# Show Processes of Shell Script

Tags: java, android, text, printing

I have the following method for running shell commands in my java applications and i'm looking to run a few scripts such as one that fixes permissions for all applications on the users phone. I can run the script no problem by using this command execCommand("/system/xbin/fix_perm"); however the problem is that i want to just print out what's being done like terminal emulator does how can i take my outputstream and print it on the screen? Thank you for any help

```
public Boolean execCommand(String command) 
{
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = rt.exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream()); 
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping you're aware of the potentially extreme consequences of allowing a user to run arbitrary commands as `su` and will instead point to a possible solution.

```
public Boolean execCommand(String command) 
{
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = rt.exec("su");

        // capture stdout
        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        // capture stderr
        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream()); 
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.flush();

        String line = null;
        StringBuilder cmdOut = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
            cmdOut.append(line);
        }
        stdout.close();
        while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
            cmdOut.append("[ERROR] ").append(line);
        }
        stderr.close();

        // Show simple dialog
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cmdOut.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        // consider dropping this, see http://kylecartmell.com/?p=9
        process.waitFor(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: does System.out.println() do anything useful on an Android device?

Comment: Not really (can be displayed in your IDE though), have changed it to use the Android logger.

Comment: Yes... but I think the OP wants to display it on the device's screen.

Comment: Yes i want to display it on the devices screen and not in the log i just want to show what's being done when i run a couple of scripts basically what a terminal emulator does minus all the code behind an emulator i only want to show the processes for a few scripts that i want to run in my app

Comment: Updated to use Toast notifications (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: Well i definately don't want to use toasts the script for fix permissions out puts a lot of stuff it fixes every app installed on the phone but i guess this is something to work with going to play with it when i get back to my dorm room and will let you guys know how it goes that is printing on the screen

Comment: So this is not what you asked for? What is missing from the answer?

Comment: Just that i want to print the processes on the screen not through toasts only cause there are going to be so many processes toasts wouldn't be a good way to show them i want to show a black screen and then just show the processes in full screen mode not through toasts